# Create and manage tables dynamically in spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm start a project in spring that is a crud-like where the user can create tables with column quantities and types according their needs, manage the table content using this application and it's going to work with mysql, oracle and sql server.

My problem is that I'm quite new in spring development and I couldn't find a way to abstract the sql other than hibernate, but I also couldn't find examples of dynamic tables in hibernate and because of the entities I can't see a way to do so.

So my question is, how can I create an application that can create and manage new tables during runtime using spring? Is hibernate the right option?

Spring and abstract sql code are the only 2 requirements for the project so as long as it works and is maintainable I'm open to other options.

Comment: If you're working with dynamic schema, you'll need to use JDBC directly. `JdbcTemplate` may be helpful.

Comment: But using `JdbcTemplate` I'd need to manage the sql code for each language right? Is there any way to at least abstract this code?

Comment: What do you mean by "each language"? All of those databases speak SQL, and you'd usually need to deal with dialect-specific idiosyncrasies in a hands-on manner anyway.